# Third party app iOS Storage usage statistics

Tags: ios, ios8

When iOS 8 was released by Apple, it came with a feature where the user could see the storage used by different third party apps. However, in case of third party apps, it only displays the total data used by the app and gives the user an option to delete the entire app.

However in case of native apple apps like Music and Video, there is granular control to actually delete the individual files in those apps.

My query is, Is there a way to provide a similar functionality in case of third party apps?

Suppose my app stores different documents created by the user, can I give a granular control to delete individual documents?

Comment: Sure. Make it a feature of your app.

Comment: @rmaddy, Could you please provide more info on how to do that? Perhaps an example or a link to apple docs? I searched the forum and was not able to find any leads.